# Interleaved closing tag error in Handlebars (Ember.js)

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I recently decided to try Ember.js.

I set up a small application, but I can't get something to work.

I have a file app.html

```
<!doctype>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/x-handlebars">
            ...
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, of course, this doesn't render anything. I include handlebars.js, ember.js, and app.js and now then everything renders properly.

The problem is that when I try to add something with curly braces, the output is blank. For example, if I set some variables in my JS files and want to display it in my app, like `<h1>{{title}}</h1>`, I get `<h1></h1>`. When I try to put `{{input value="Username"}}`, nothing gets displayed.

I get no error messages, except when I use closing tags. For example, this

```
{{#link-to "http://google.ca"}}Link{{/link-to}}
```

Will make my whole web page simply display

```
line 117: interleaved closing tag: link-to
```

I have no idea what is wrong. Even googling the error message doesn't help much.

Any hint?ç

**UPDATE**

This code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/2.1.0/normalize.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
        <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.8.0/ember.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            App = Ember.Application.create();
            App.Router.map(function() {
                // put your routes here
            });
            App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
                model: function() {
                    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/x-handlebars">
            <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
                {{outlet}}
        </script>
        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
                <a href="http://google.ca">Link</a>
                <ul>
                    {{#each item in model}}
                        <li>{{item}}</li>
                    {{/each}}
                </ul>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Renders a blank page with this error message:

```
line 36: interleaved closing tag: each
```

I'm not sure that's normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and this is really stupid.

My HTML files are delivered by a framework that uses Mustache as its template engine (server side) and therefore it renders all the `{{something}}` tags before sending the output to the broswer.

:/

Answer (score 0):

link-to is meant for ember routes only. (http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/)

In your case I would just write the html for the link in the template directly.

Here is a small sample ember.js app with the google.ca link, I have a feeling that your html may not be  setup correctly with an outlet and a template:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qivunivabo/3/edit

Comment: What about the input and the rest? Everything fails, even the built-in helpers like `if`. They all render nothing, or, when a closing is used, the error `interleaved closing tag:` appears.

Comment: Update: Your jsbin link works fine, but when I copied and pasted the code locally, I got the same error again: `interleaved closing tag: each`. :/